# Connect coordinates only according to specifications in an Excel list

Tags: qgis, excel

I have an Excel list with coordinates of shops and their names. I want to connect certain coordinates with the help of a second list.

The second list contains in the first row and column the names of the shops. If there is a visual relationship between the shops, the list contains a "1" otherwise the field is empty.

Is there a possibility in QGIS to connect only those coordinates, where a "1" is entered in the second list?

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stackexchange. You can have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html), which is about  table joins in QGIS. It may be a good starting point for you. You can export your excel sheets as csv, so that they are more easy to work with in QGIS.

Comment: Thanks for the Tutorial tip! That I still have to convert all tables into a csv file is clear to me. But I don't know how to correctly import the contents of the second table so that qgis understands that the coordinates should only be connected if there is a "1" in the table.

Comment: What do you mean by "connect coordinates" - do you want to draw a line between the two shops? Or do you want them linked in the attribute table? Either way I think the format of your second table will be a problem.